# Restore grub2 - update error 08/08/2021 in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: partitioning, grub2, 20.04, updates, uefi

I have ubuntu 20.04 in dualboot with windows 10.

I just updated ubuntu 20.04 and apparently grub2 is not working anymore. This error appears: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNGUL.jpg .

Is there a way I can solve it from the windows 10 partition?

thanks in advance,

Pablo

Comment: I restore grub with a live usb. But now, when I enter in windows, and restart, the same problem appears again.

Comment: In any dual-boot disabling the Windows Fast Startup feature is a must.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI firmware? And if SSD updated SSD firmware?  What brand/model system. Some only let you change boot order from within UEFI settings & boot tab (not the UEFI boot menu).

Comment: Finally, after many attempts, an ubuntu update 2 weeks ago solved the problem.

Every time I wanted to access ubuntu it had to be through a liveusb to repair EFI.